# Conteúdo renderizado por trás da StatusBar

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou fazendo um curso onde a tela do app deveria está dessa maneira, com o componente no topo não ultrapassando o limite do layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém no meu código ficou desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dá para ver até que o ícone foi cortado.

Segue o codigo do App.js, que está igual o do curso.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import Topo from './componentes/Topo';
import Texto from './componentes/Texto';
import Cards from './componentes/Cards';

export default function App () { 
return (
  <View>
    <Topo />
    <Texto />
    <Cards />
  </View>
);
}
```

O código do componente (`Topo`) index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import estilo from './estilo'
import churrasco from '../../assets/churrasco.png';

export default function Topo() {
  return (
    <View style={estilo.box}>
      <Image style={estilo.boxIcone} source = { churrasco } />

      <View>
        <Text style={estilo.boxTitulo}>Churrasco em casa</Text>
        <Text style={estilo.boxSubtitulo}>Calculando a comida e a bebida</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Eu acho que talvez possa ser a versão, já que esse curso deve ter um pouquinho de tempo.

Vocês podem me esclarecer por que isso acontece? E qual a solução?

Comment: Alguma resposta te ajudou? Dê uma olhada no [tour] e saiba como aceitar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No começo de um curso sobre React Native, tive um problema parecido, mesmo seguindo o tutorial a parte de cima ficava cortando, no começo coloquei apenas um `marginTop: 20`, então percebi que o problema é o `StatusBar`, acho que em versões anteriores ele já vinha automático, agora você tem que chamar-lo.

Você pode colocar uma marginTop na view:

```
<View style={estilo.box, {marginTop: 20}}>
      <Image style={estilo.boxIcone} source = { churrasco } />
  <View>
    <Text style={estilo.boxTitulo}>Churrasco em casa</Text>
    <Text style={estilo.boxSubtitulo}>Calculando a comida e a bebida</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

OU

Você pode colocar a StatusBar no App.js, aconselho fazer isso: (Lembrar de colocar (<> </>) no inicio e no fim do return)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import Routes from "./src/routes/routes";

export default function App({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#3e91e4" />
      <Routes />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Era o statusbar mesmo, ele realmente não vem automatico como em versões passadas.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, boa noite. pelo que pude compreender sua dúvida é em relação a ao cabeçalho que corta o seu component, certo? Você pode ocultar o mesmo, mas vale ressaltar que a implementação depende da versão do [stack navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) que está usando.

A partir da versão 5 você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<Stack.Navigator
 screenOptions={{
   headerShown: false 
  }}>
 <Stack.Screen name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Caso fique com dúvida só mandar, que tentarei explicar melhor pra você.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que sua tela não está considerando o tamanho da [`StatusBar`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar).

Por exemplo, quando a `StatusBar` está com a propriedade [`translucent`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#translucent) definida o aplicativo será renderizado por trás dela, o que pode ser útil em algumas situações, mas é um problema no seu caso.

Para resolver você pode renderizar a `<StatusBar />` no componente que lhe convém, porém sem definir a propriedade `translucent`. Vale ressaltar que mesmo que você renderize a `<StatusBar />` em vários componentes, o React Native considerará a última renderizada.

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor='#fff' barStyle='dark-content' />
```

<sup>Caso esteja utilizando o Expo, utilize o [expo-status-bar](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/status-bar/).</sup>

Outra opção é fazer uso da [`SafeAreaView`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview) como *root* do seu componente ao invés de uma `View`. O funcionamento é o mesmo da `View`, porém a `SafeAreaView` leva em consideração alguns detalhes (como a `StatusBar`, barras de navegação, tab etc.) e adiciona um `padding`:

```
<SafeAreaView>
  {/* componentes */}
</SafeAreaView>
```

<sup>Também existe o [react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context). Caso esteja utilizando o Expo, veja [aqui](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/)</sup>

Note que é preferível utilizar `SafeAreaView` ao invés de você colocar um estilo manual pois o tamanho da tela disponível varia de acordo com o dispositivo e também OS (Android / iOS).